# Spatial offset when using gdal_translate with projwin

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I am using `gdal_translate` with a custom `projwin` to select a subwindow from an [ESA WorldCover](https://esa-worldcover.org/en) source dataset. The dataset comes in EPSG:4326 and the command looks as follows:

```bash
export AWS_NO_SIGN_REQUEST=YES

gdal_translate \
    -projwin -123.2232 42.3036 -123.2228 42.3032 \
    -of Gtiff \
    /vsicurl/https://esa-worldcover.s3.amazonaws.com/v100/2020/ESA_WorldCover_10m_2020_v100_Map_AWS.vrt \
    ~/file2c2538bf635a.tif
```

Upon investigating the output image (colored tiles below), I found that it does not quite line up with the specified `projwin` (polygon with black dashed borders). My question is, why are the source pixels intersecting with the subwindow at the bottom and right side not included in the output? For the record, I know there are many more rows/columns at the bottom/right in the `src_dataset` from testing with a larger `projwin`.

Especially those pixels at the bottom should have a much higher overlap with the specified `projwin` than for example the pixels at the top. Nonetheless, the top row is included in the output, whereas the bottom row is not.

[image: gdal_translate_projwin_offset]

My GDAL version is `GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22`.

Comment: fwiw I need to do 'export AWS_NO_SIGN_REQUEST=YES' before running that cmd

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I made some comments on twitter that *you already understand*, so I've constructed a better response - the answer imo is "there are different approaches taken for pixel alignment", and terra with its in/near/out options are different to gdal's still   - I might write up in more detail, great topic - thanks! uncovers lots of interesting details for me ;) https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/5d7b156611a6fa267dfe368ea6e2a385